# Python PDF extraction - key value pair

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pymupdf

I have a non-editable pdf file which contains fields and checkbox data. I have a python script which should capture the data into a dictionary but ends up:

1. Listing all the key values first, then all their pair values separately thereafter.
2. Does not read any checkbox data.

PyMuPDF is being used.

I tried the code below:

```
import fitz  
import pandas as pd
import re

# Function to clean text
def clean_text(text):
    return re.sub('\\s+', ' ', text).strip()

def is_field_name(line):
    # A field name is likely to end with a colon followed by an optional space
    return bool(re.match(r'.*:\\s*$', line))

# Function to determine if the next line is a checkbox indicator

def is_checkbox(line):
    # Looking for lines that have a checkbox indication, e.g., "\[X\] Yes" or "\[ \] No"
    return bool(re.match(r'\[(X| )\]\\s\*(Yes|No)', line))

pdf_document = fitz.open('PTO 2024.pdf')

page = pdf_document[0]
text = page.get_text("text")

pdf_document.close()

lines = text.split('\\n')

extracted_data = {}
current_field = None

# Process each line, assuming that fields are followed by their values or checkboxes
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = clean_text(line)
    if is_field_name(line):
        # The current line is a field name
        current_field = line[:-1]  # Remove the colon at the end
    elif current_field:
        if is_checkbox(line):
            # Line is a checkbox indicator, e.g., "\[X\] Yes"
            extracted_data[current_field] = 'Checked' if 'Yes' in line else 'Unchecked'
            current_field = None  # Reset current field after capturing checkbox
        elif line:
            # Line has content and is not a checkbox, so it's a value for the current field
            extracted_data[current_field] = line
            current_field = None  # Reset current field after capturing value

df_extracted = pd.DataFrame(list(extracted_data.items()), columns=['Field', 'Value'])

print("Extracted Lines:")
for line in lines:
    print(line)

print("\\nExtracted Data:")
print(df_extracted.head())
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you regular expression `\\s+` has mistake. It matches `\s`, `\s\s`, ..., not one or more spaces as you expected.

Comment: @MatveyPolubryukhov I didn't realize at the time, but when I pasted in the code, additional  backslashes(\) were added.  Its really:
def clean_text(text):
    return re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip()

Comment: @KJ there is private data on the pdf so I wont be able link it. I called it non-editable on an assumption. When double clicking anywhere on this pdf, I don't get an option to select data. Also, I tried tabula and PyPDF2 but they cant seem to find any objects on the pdf file.

Comment: You are not looking for real PDF form fields - only for text. Why is that so? To recognize a portion of text as being a flattened checkbox (real checkbox converted to text), then you are on shaky grounds, because that may have been done by different methods - ranging from little square vector graphics to using unicodes 0x2610, 0x2611, 0x2612, giving '☐', '☑', '☒'.